# How to get access to list of files in directory from fragment?

Tags: android

Last line gives Unreachable Statement error. How to fix it?

```
   public class ListenFragment extends Fragment {

    private String[] files;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup 
container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listen, container, false);

        files = getActivity().getDir("voices", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).list();

    }
}
```

Comment: everything after "return" is unreachable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unreachable Statement error can be fixed by this way :

```
public class ListenFragment extends Fragment {

    private String[] files;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        files = getActivity().getDir("voices", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).list();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listen, container, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ListenFragment extends Fragment {

    private String[] files;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listen, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        files = getActivity().getDir("voices", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).list();
    }
}
```